# C# PowerPoint 2007 management: .Hyperlink.Address always NULL

Tags: c#, hyperlink, ip-address, powerpoint

I have this problem, I use :

```
//someWord is a TextRange object from PPT TextBox
String address = someWord.ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address;
```

I'm sure that this is the way to read address to webpages in a link, I was using this in PPT 2003, and it works!
BUT, now I'm trying to do the same **in PPT 2007 and the .Hyperlink.Address is always equal to null**.

Any suggestion? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the URL is couched in a set of runs. Like if you had a text box that looked like this:

> A search engine: [Ask Jeeves](http://www.ask.com)

It technically has two runs. Try both of these in VBA and see if one or both (or none) work:

```
Sub getHyperlinkfromTextRun()
    Dim sl As Slide: Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
    Dim sh As Shape: Set sh = sl.Shapes(1)
    Dim tr As TextRange: Set tr = sh.TextFrame.TextRange
    Dim URL As String
    For i = 1 To tr.Runs.Count
        URL = tr.Runs(i).ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.Address
        If Len(URL) > 0 Then
            Dim runText As String
            runText = tr.Runs(i).Text
            Debug.Print "RUN " & i & ": " & runText & ", " & "URL: " & URL
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub getHyperlinkfromTextRange()
    Dim sl As Slide: Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
    Dim sh As Shape: Set sh = sl.Shapes(1)
    Dim tr As TextRange: Set tr = sh.TextFrame.TextRange
    Debug.Print tr.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.Address
End Sub
```